# Audio and Video controller

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two slides in HTML.
Slide 1 has Audio and its own default controller.

```
<audio id="audio-player" autoplay controls>
            <source class="track" src="audio/play-1.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
```

Slide 2 has a Video and it has its own default controller.

```
<video controls class="slide2_1" src="images/Slide2_1.mp4"></video>
```

An Audio controller remains to fix position in every slide.

Now, I don't want to use a Video controller to play Video. Instead, I want to use an Audio controller on behalf of the Video Controller.

Is this possible with help of JavaScript?

I know it looks awkward but the client wants the one controller for Audio and Video.